# SCP timeout when running through a script when connected to a remote machine through ssh

Tags: ssh, tcl, scp

I'm trying to run the following scenario, using TCL script -

Scenario -
Host A runs the TCL script. Host A script connects to Host B through ssh. Then the script invokes an scp file transfer from Host C (server) to Host B (client).

Problem - 
The script doesn't actually implement a timeout scenario. However, scp fails with no error message exactly after 10 seconds(probably timeout). If done manually, i.e. Logging in to Host B from Host A, and then scp from Host C to Host B, there is no timeout observed, and the file transfer is successful.

Implemented the ssh connection from tcl script using "expect" package.
What could be the reason? Kindly suggest some solutions.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried using the `-v` option (verbose mode) to scp? Without knowing what might be failing, guessing how to fix it is a _little bit_ difficult…

Comment: There seems to be no issue with scp, it seems there is an issue with the "expect" package. Is there a timeout for expect function?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant source code from these scripts.

Comment: Are you looking for `set timeout -1` ?? This will stop expect from timing out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set

```
RSAAuthentication yes
```

on Host C, add the public key of Host B's user to Host C's user authorized_keys file?

See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2 for more details.

Simple test:
Try to run the scp manually (or try ssh): It shouldn't ask you for a password. Running *ssh -v* from Host B to Host C should include the following lines:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/xyz/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 1047
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

Comment: The script takes care of providing the password when necessary. Also, with scp, I use the option "StrictHostKeyChecking=no". The file transfer starts and runs for 10 seconds. If there was an issue with authorization, the file transfer shouldn't start? I'm not very clear about that though.